# Can partisan support among whites be predicted by physical appearance?

Tags: election, voting, ideology

Are there documented patterns of political preference based on appearance?

Note, I'd like to keep the answers focused on white people, as there are obvious relationships between race -> appearance and race -> partisanship.

Comment: I don't claim that the anecdote is reflective of the general population.  However, there might be some other trends that *are* present in the general population, and I'm interested in learning about them.

Comment: Secondly, the phrase "white people do not have blonde hair" does not logically invalidate an anecdote - you'd have to speak in particular to the group of people I'm referring to.

Comment: Thirdly, the phrase that "a majority of white people support republicans" does not negate the possibility of there being different categories of white people who support republicans at significantly different rates, which is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Selection bias does not set the foundation of a good question.

Comment: origimbo, that's closer to what I'm looking for, but I'm more interested in traits that aren't obvious.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic, I am disappointed by your inability to differentiate between the phrase "X is a pattern I've noticed and I'm curious about whether this is universal and the existence of similar patterns" and the claim that "X is a universally occurring pattern."  Nevertheless, I have edited the question to clarify what I'm referring to.

Comment: That is the very premise of selection bias. Attempting to apply a trend from a narrow, unrepresentative population, to the larger population.

Comment: At no point was I attempting to apply that particular trend - it was only meant to serve as an example of the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - or, applying Bayesian reasoning in insufficient information  space...

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing that some organizations somewhere might have studied, and I can imagine an answer to such a question that cites such hypothetical studies.

Answer (score 1):

I only have anecdotal evidence, but the answer is a resounding no.

I work in IT, and am about an hour from DC and Baltimore. The majority of people who work here are above average when it comes to education, dress up for work, and are very well spoken; so, most people would suspect them to be liberal, but they are mostly conservative.

With that being said, it is in WV, but the far eastern tip of the panhandle. So, as is known, location plays a much bigger role in political affiliation than appearance.

For example, the south is conservative. So, you will have people from all walks of life be conservative. Whether they are white collar workers, wealthy businessmen, blue collar workers, or rednecks.

The same applies in the northeast, and west coast. They are liberal bastions, but just cause someone is wearing fancy clothes in a city doesn't mean they are liberal. There are plenty of upper class republicans in these areas.

With that being said there are certain groups like hipsters that dress, let's just say exotically, that are most definitely liberal. Same with rednecks that wear rebel flag tshirts are definitely conservative. But these groups publically state their political affiliation by dressing to display their social groups. They might as well wear a sign saying who they support.

But, overall, for most people who dress traditionally there is no easy way to tell which political party they support.